# Synapse for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-recommendation, repository

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04. I'm disappointed to see synapse gone from `Ubuntu Software Centre`. I've added repository available in Launchpad. It resulted in error 404.

How can I install synapse?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Bleeding Edge PPA:

```
ppa:synapse-core/testing
```

It contains Synapse for Ubuntu 14.04.

[image: The real synapse]

Comment: That magnifying glass looks cool. What theme settings did you use?

Comment: @Exeleration-G Numix Circle.